# php curl data scraping

Tags: php, curl

I have a CURL code to fetch data from a site it is working fine for last few months but suddenly stop working for me it says

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily
```

my code is:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $baseUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy[0]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy[1]);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE         , $phpSId);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      , $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     , $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT      , "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        , 40);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST , 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL            , $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER         , 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST           , 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     , $data);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
unset($ch); 
die($result);
```

Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question? How are we supposed to know what changed on the server you're scraping? Can you give us the URL you're polling?

Comment: Why don't you give us an example URL so we can check for ourselves?

Comment: yeah, that's a redirect to another URL, so, follow it in your browser, and replace the URL you were trying with the new one

Comment: they have blocked my ip and i don't know how they blocked proxy servers, when i am using dynamic proxy server they redirect me to a page with error "group not allowed", how we can block proxies on a php server?

Comment: i have to scrap photofunia[dot]com with dynamic proxy

Comment: they have detected the proxy address when i remove proxy it works fine is it possible to get non public proxy lists?

Answer (score 1):

The specified options already make curl follow redirects. However, in the case of a long redirect chain, you may want to increase `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS`.

You can use a packet dumper such as [wireshark](http://wireshark.org) to check which requests are sent by curl. It may be simply a bug in the scraped website which causes it to redirect infinitely.

Comment: @gauravstomar  you can analyze the redirects a little faster with a web browser compared to wireshark if you are not familiar with wireshark.  Just look at the http headers to see how many redirects are occuring.  Then set `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` appropriatly

Comment: @JM. There may be some specific anti-curl or JavaScript-required trickery involved. Setting `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` to, say, 1000, should be more than any browser accepts.

Comment: actually they have blocked proxy access to there website, how it is possible?

Comment: @gauravstomar Some proxies set an `X-Forwarded-For` header, and there are public proxy datbases. Are you certain that the proxy is the problem, and not curl? Oftentimes, changing the User-Agent header is enough to evade such silly blockades or misconfigurations.

Comment: they have detected the proxy address when i remove proxy it works fine is it possible to get non public proxy lists?

Comment: @gauravstomar Sure, just setting up a proxy and not telling anyone should suffice. If you want to be extra certain, restrict access to the proxy by requiring a specific IP (block) or a VPN connection.

Comment: @gauravstomar php is not really the best way to set up a proxy, although there are existing [implementations](https://bitbucket.org/arkadi/phpproxy). Basically, you use [`curl`](http://php.net/curl) to set up a new HTTP request. However, it's way easier **not** to use php and use a regular proxy such as [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) or apache with [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).